# Three arrows in a circle in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I'm wondering how to draw the following image in TikZ:

[image: Three overlapping arrows in a circle]

As opposed to a [known low-level solution](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/overlapping-arrows/) to a similar problem, I'm wondering whether it is possible to operate with high-level concepts such as arrows (rather than going down to the level of arcs and lines). Notice that gray borders are required and shadows are not required.

Comment: the simplest way is in answer which you aware. less simple way might be use of nonlinear canvas transformation. challenge for some `tikz` programming guru/enthusiast :-)  or compose arrows whit two stacked arrows. bigger one is gray, smaller, covered it, is for example yellow ...

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\arrow{
 (90:.9cm) -- (90:.7cm) -- (110:1.2) -- (90:1.7cm) -- (90:1.5cm)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thin]

\draw [gray,fill=yellow!50] circle(1.5);
\draw [gray,fill=white] circle(.9); 

\foreach \ang in {0,120,240} {
 \path[rotate=\ang,fill=yellow!50] \arrow --cycle;
 \draw[draw=gray,rotate=\ang] \arrow;
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

You can also set an isosceles triangle by changing the `\arrow` command like this:

```
\def\arrow{
 (0,.9) -- (0,.7) -- (-.4,1.2) -- (0,1.7) -- (0,1.5)
}
```

in which case, you will get these nice curved arrows:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The arrow shape is obtained with `slices arrow={1}{-0.5}`. The first argument is `1` such that the arrow is rectangular. The second argument is `-0.5`, the inner radius is `2` and the outer radius is `3`. Hence the distance that the arrow protrudes is `0.25`. Thus the option `gap=0.125` is used to not let the arrows overlap.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  gap=0.125,
  slices arrow={1}{-0.5},
  slices style={fill=yellow!40,draw=gray},
  total count=3
]{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `arrows.meta` and `bendings` and now with border.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta,bending}
\newcommand{\ThirdArrow}[1][]{%
\draw[line width=0.82cm,gray,-{Triangle[angle=60:.5cm 1,bend]},#1] (-74.5:1.6)
arc (-74.5:74.5:1.6 and 1.6);
\draw[line width=0.8cm,yellow!50,-{Triangle[angle=60:.5cm 1,bend]},#1] (-74:1.6) arc (-74:74:1.6 and 1.6);
}     
\newcommand{\ExtraArrow}[1][]{%
\draw[line width=0.82cm,gray,-{Triangle[angle=60:.5cm 1,bend]},#1] (0:1.6)
arc (0:74.5:1.6 and 1.6);
\draw[line width=0.8cm,yellow!50,-{Triangle[angle=60:.5cm 1,bend]},#1] 
(-0.1:1.6) arc (0:74.1:1.6 and 1.6);
}     


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ThirdArrow
\ThirdArrow[rotate=120]
\ThirdArrow[rotate=240]
\ExtraArrow
\ExtraArrow[rotate=120]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @VasiliPupkin Yes, I didn't notice the gray unwanted line. And the bending is on purpose because IMHO opinion it looks nicer.

Comment: Thanks again. So you are drawing the gray triangle and then the yellow on top? That's ok, except that borders do not have constant thickness. Still, it's ok for my purposes; thanks again.

Comment: @VasiliPupkin Yes, one can tune the distances. I'll do it in a bit.